# Import SVG from XML file and display with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I am trying to create and display SVG  with Javascript, importing the SVG elements from an external XML file. I have so far...

the external XML:

```
<letter id="A">
    <svg viewBox="0,0,4,5" height="20mm">
        <polygon points="0,5 1.5,0 2.5,0 1,5" fill="#000000" />
        <polygon points="4,5 2.5,0 1.5,0 3,5" fill="#000000" />
        <polygon points="1,3 3,3 3,4 1,4" fill="#000000" />
    </svg>
</letter>
```

etc.

imported it with XML Parser:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","NAME OF XML FILE",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
var svg=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("letter")[0].childNodes[0];
```

...now how do I display the SVG programmatically?

If I do this...

```
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var letter=document.createElementNS(NS,"svg");
var svg=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("letter")[0].firstChild;
letter.appendChild(svg);
document.write(letter);
```

I get [object SVGSVGElement] in my document but the graphic is not displayed.

Comment: Add the root node to your document somewhere.

Comment: I've edited my question to demonstrate that I'm failing at doing this.

Comment: Don't think you can use document.write to change from an html document to an svg document. You'll need to use document.documentElement.appendChild(letter)

Comment: No that's not working either

Comment: The code for IE6 and IE5 isn't really needed since those versions don't support svg anyway. Just look at the resulting DOM in a web inspector, make sure the svg elements all have a non-zero width and height, and note that if you have that wrapper <letter> inside an <svg> it will make all children of the <letter> element not render (since it's an unknown element).